# Paypal IPN keep showing INVALID

Tags: php, paypal, paypal-ipn

I am trying IPN callback but everytime I try to validate the IPN message with paypal it says that is **INVALID**!
I already tried a lot of methods in the internet but anyone is working,
This is my code:

```
header('HTTP/1.1 200 OK');
$req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value) {
$value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
$req .= "&$key=$value";
$homepage = file_get_contents("https://ipnpb.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr?{$req}");
```

This is working but its showing invalid.
Does someone knows why this is happening?

Comment: Please put your code in the post, not a link of the code.

Comment: Cant because says that the content is most code and dont let me submit

Comment: Ok, then I'm flagging to close this question.

Comment: I modified the code now is in the post

Comment: Is that your full code? Because it's not valid PHP. Also, have you considered using a library that does this for you? Something like https://github.com/angelleye/paypal-ipn-template

Comment: no its not but the other part is not a problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved,

The Paypal IPN simulator have an error, just remove the DATE field when you going to simulate and you will get VERIFIED!

Answer (score 0):

I think you must send data to PayPal in a POST request, not GET!